# AWS | ELB Redirect SSL Enabled IP to Domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, seo

I believe this is an important point and there is no help out there on the web.

**Problem**

I want to redirect my IP to the domain. for example, https://74.127.128.193/ and ELB URL hfgjg-77665555.ap-south-1.elb.amazonaws.com need to be 301 redirected to sample.com.

I want this because this IP and ELB URL is indexed by Google and instead of showing pages from domain google showing pages from that IP and ELB URL and marking many pages of the domain as duplicate because they are already index with IP address.

**Tried Following**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^74\.127\.128\.193$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://google.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This is working but with http only, I mean this is redirecting IP to Domain when I open IP with http.

But his is not redirecting from IP to the domain when I open IP with https and Google has indexed IP with https not http.

I believe this is a huge problem in SEO and this is happening to everyone who is using AWS ELB with SSL, but they have not think about this or have not gone that deep as much I have gone.

Comment: Uhm... you typically don't redirect domains. You use a DNS entry to point to that IP when people type your domain name in. So you need an A record pointed to that IP

Comment: Rather than look for the IP address specifically why not put in a redirect rule to redirect to your hostname if the HTTP_HOST doesn't match your hostname?  `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com [NC]`  That way if your ELB changes its IP address your redirect still works.

Comment: The correct way to handle the SEO implications is to add a `canonical` tag to your site to instruct Google and other search engines what the primary domain name is. https://moz.com/learn/seo/canonicalization

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got it working.

Thanks for your reply guys.

Google was showing my website has three different versions and it is hurting my website ranking since so long. My website content was showing in google with following.

1. Website IP address
2. ELB URL
3. My domain

The above code in my question was actually working but when I was accessing IP with https in chrome it was asking for permission to open the URL and at that time IP was not redirecting to the domain but once I allow the permission it was redirecting successfully.

I have redirected from IP and ELB URL to domain successfully with following code in my htaccess file at top.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^hfgjg-77665555\.ap-south-1\.elb\.amazonaws\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) https://sample.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^74\.127\.128\.193
RewriteRule (.*) https://sample.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

NOTE: This will permanently redirect all the internal pages as well to the domain